# Data type for 2 decimal places?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

Which datatype should I be using to give me a number with 2 decimal places?

I currently have the following line:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@miles", SqlDbType.Decimal, 2).Value = miles;
```

and I am not sure what `SqlDbType.Decimal, 4` means in terms of decimal places?

Will that allow the following

```
123.32
123321.67
```

and not allow numbers like

```
123
123.123321
543345.5434523
324.1
```

Comment: Why not format the value before sending to DB? And i guess you would use decimal

Comment: You really need to read the documentation on [`decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx). The 4 stands for the precision. You need to use an overload that also takes the scale (2, in your case).

Comment: @Duane, Just trying to be extra strict...

Comment: @Oded, I guess that is the part I didn't get, how to get both the precision value and the scale value into the `command.Parameters.Add` line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `decimal` you need to specify both the precision and scale of the parameter.

You do this by constructing the parameter (using `new`) and adding it.

The two last constructor overloads in the [`SqlParameter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) MSDN page have arguments for precision and scale.

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can try with Scale in order to format your parameter

```
 SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("miles", SqlDbType.Decimal);
 parameter.Scale = 2; //The number of positions

http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.scale.aspx
```

Comment: That's a normal input parameter, not an output parameter.

Comment: Ok i inderstand your advice Thank's Oded